# Change size of Card in Drawer

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
I need to change the size of the cards so they are longer vertically.

```
child:Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('DRAWER HEADER',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Colors.deepPurple.shade300),
        ),
            Card(
              color: Colors.deepPurple.shade300,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hi',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                onTap:(){debugPrint('Add');},
              )
            ),
),
```

Comment: could you provide an image or representation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: ive uploaded a photo, I'm trying to make them bigger basically, so they're longer vertically.

Comment: Check my answer, that should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that goal in many ways:

- You can add Padding inside your Text
- Containers have a height parameter

or you could use SizedBox and then your Card inside, like this:

```
int listLength = 8; // The size of your List, this will vary.

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Drawer + Card"),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listLength + 1, // + 1 is to handle your Header
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return index == 0
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: 160,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade300,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            "DRAWER HEADER",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : SizedBox(
                      height: 80, // Change this size to make it bigger or smaller
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade300,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              "Index $index",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The end result is what you're looking for:

[image: Drawer + Card]

Comment: how would I add a drawer header to this?

Comment: check my updated response. That will add your header.